# How can I capture the self written logs in log file

Tags: powershell

Could you please take a look and let me know, what I missed. actually, I am not getting capture the complete self-written logs in a log file. Also, if someone let me know how can add the email function in this email as well.

```
 $Source='c:\uploadtool\*'  # Source location, from where file will be transferred to destination
    $RetailDest= "D:\ToolUpload\Retail-EIP" # Destination location 1
    $GroupDest= "D:\ToolUpload\Group-EIP"   # Destination Location 2
    $RetailBack="D:\ToolUpload\Retail-EIP\*"   # Source for backup copy
    $GroupBack="D:\ToolUpload\Group-EIP\*"     # Source for backup copy
    $filename = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -File -Force -Recurse  
    $Backupdata="D:\Backup"    # Backup location
    $logname="D:\logs\uploadlog_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd').txt"   #Log file will be create in D drive
    echo " Date is : " (Get-Date -Format 'dd-MM-yyyy') | Out-File $logname -Append
    echo "Source is:  $filename" | out-file $logname -Append
    echo  "File size =  "($filename).Length | out-file $logname 
    #echo "               " | out-file $logname -Append
    $ArchiveData = New-Item -Path "$Backupdata\backup_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddHHMM')" -Force - ItemType Directory  # This will create a new directory for backup with current date and time.
 
    foreach($file in $filename)
    {
    try
    {
    if($file -match "Retail-EIP")  # First condition will match the string name with "Retail-EIP" and copy the new file to 1st destination location ("D:\ToolUpload\Retail-EIP")
    {
    
     $fname=$file.fullname
     Move-Item -Path $RetailBack -Destination $ArchiveData  # this will be backup an existing file first on backup location.
     echo "File copying start" | Out-File $logname -Append
     Move-Item -Path $fname -Destination $RetailDest
     echo "File has been upload to Retail Platform: $fname" |out-file $logname
    }
    }
    catch{
    throw $_.Exception.Message | out-file $logname -Append
    }
    if($file -match "Group-EIP")  #This will match the string name with "Group EIP" if the condition satisfies then the file will be copied to 2nd Destination Location ("D:\ToolUpload\Group-EIP").
    {
    
     $fname=$file.fullname
     Move-Item -Path $GroupBack -Destination $ArchiveData
     echo "File has been backed up :$GroupBack" | out-file $logname
     Move-Item -Path $fname -Destination $GroupDest
     echo "File has been upload to Group Platform: $fname" |out-file $logname
    }
    }
```

Here I am not getting proper logs in the log file, what I want -

Before starting copy, it should capture in the log file as below

File Source name like if the file match to "Retail-EIP" or "Group-EIP"

The file source is "C:\uploadtool\Retail-EIP or Group-EIP.

The file size is 24 MB

The file is copying to Destination Location

The file is copied to the Retail or Group location.

Please help to complete this script so that I can present this to my lead.

Comment: You need to make sure **all** output directories exist and if not create them first. Also, sometimes you try to append to the log, but other times you forget that, so if there was a log file written, you will overwrite it again.. I'd change `echo "whatever message" |out-file $logname` into `"whatever message" | Add-Content -Path $logname -PassThru`

Answer (score 0):

To create a log file you must create a Directory and then create file by providing ItemType

Create Folder

```
    $logFolderName="D:\logs"
    
    $logFileName="D:\logs\uploadlog_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd').txt"
    
    $checkLocalFolderExist = Test-Path -Path $logFolderName
    
    $checkLocalFileExist = Test-Path -Path $logFileName  -PathType Leaf
     if(-NOT $checkLocalFolderExist)
    {
      New-Item -Path $logFolderName -ItemType Directory
    }
    
    if(-NOT $checkLocalFileExist)
    {
      New-Item -Path $logFileName -ItemType File
    }

echo " Date is : " (Get-Date -Format 'dd-MM-yyyy') | Out-File $logFileName -Append
```

Now, as your log file is created. You can insert your logs.

If you want to log exception logs also. Then, this is how your code should be.

```
Try 
{
 # executing command here
}

#Error handling in case of command failure
Catch {
  #below code will capture the exception message
  # $_.Exception.Message
  echo " Date is : " (Get-Date -Format 'dd-MM-yyyy') $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logFileName -Append 

}
```

Comment: Hi Narendra, Thank you so much for your prompt response on this, First of all, I would like to say thanks, it works but using code "New-Item -Path $logname -ItemType File", it throws an error that the file is already created.

Comment: Hi Essex, I have edited the code. This will working according to your requirement. Please vote the answer if this helps.

Comment: Hi Narendra, It works now. Thank you for your extreme help on this. I vote you 10

Comment: Hi Narendra, one more help needed if possible could you please help, How can I generate a self-written error in the catch statement. And do you provide classes on PowerShell

Comment: Hi Essex, I have updated the code to capture logs in catch block. Please make this answer as useful, if it really helped you.

Comment: Hi Narendra, Thank you for looking into this but it doesn't capture the Catch message in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your `Out-File` is missing the `-Append` switch which overwrites all the previous logs. I assume you are currently getting only the last message in the log file.

`Send-Mailmessage` will tackle your email problem. However, wont be able to speak towards the finer details without knowing what kind of mail server you use.

Comment: Hi Sid, Yes you are right all logs overwrite and I am only getting the last one and we are using O365 mail server.